# paper-header-panel - Can not style the shadow

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using *Polymer 1.1*, I want to make the drop shadow permanent on `paper-header-panel`....even if I am not scrolling. But right now, I can not style the shadow at all. This style I applied when scrolling doesn't take effect. It should be quit noticable at 100px:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  paper-header-panel {
      --paper-header-panel-shadow: {
         box-shadow: inset 100px 100px 100px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
</style>

  </head>
  <body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <paper-header-panel mode="waterfall-tall" class="flex">
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div class='title'></div>
        <paper-tabs>
          <paper-tab>
            <div>contact</div>
          </paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
        <div class='title bottom'>
          <h1 id="name-title">Foo</h1>
        </div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div style="height: 2000px">
        <section hero>
          <h2>Bar</h2>
        </section>
      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </body>
```

What am I doing wrong? This is according to the documentation https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-header-panel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the *height* of the shadow, merely increasing the second parameter (i.e. the `vertical length` of the shadow) is not enough, you also need to give the *drapshadow* `div` a bigger `height`, like this -

```
  paper-header-panel {
      --paper-header-panel-shadow: {
        height: 24px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 24px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      };
  }
```

Note that I also updated the `box-shadow` to have more reasonable attributes.

Comment: I tried this also but no success. The other way would of been equivalent to https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-header-panel/blob/master/demo/index.html#L31

Comment: Hmm... Have a look at this (http://plnkr.co/edit/tzVenBH9kUh83pQNpXsm?p=preview), is this what you want? See the shadow appear after it's condensed.

Comment: I see a shadow when it's condensed, but not one that is 100px or even close to that size. It looks like it's using https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-header-panel/blob/master/paper-header-panel.css#L15 instead.

Comment: OK, I see what you want now, you also want to increase the `height` and maybe make the shadow attributes a bit more reasonable. See this (http://plnkr.co/edit/tzVenBH9kUh83pQNpXsm?p=preview).

Comment: I don't want something reasonable, I want something to show there isn't a change taking effect. Please see this... http://plnkr.co/edit/NjYmhWYesQMxhB6WjniU?p=preview . I changed the height and I changed the shadow to 100px but there is no visible change when condensed.

Comment: Well I think you missed my updated answer. You also need to increase the `height` of the shadow. Just change the `height` from `24px` to `100px`, and you will see the difference.

Comment: `height: 100px;
        box-shadow: inset 100px 100px 100px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);`

Comment: Wow...I think I see the issue. My browser at home would not show the difference but at work I see the difference with another browser ver. When I get home I will triple check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause:

It turns out that a new version of Chrome is not responding Polymer API while an older version of chromium is.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2307